# Prove there exist a basis $V$ and a basis $W$ such that all entries of $\mathcal{M}(T)$ are 0 except row j and column j

Tags: linear-algebra

This is question 3 of Exercise 3.C in Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right:

Suppose  and  are finite-dimensional and  is a linear map from  to . Prove that there exist a basis of  and a basis of  such that with respect to these bases, all entries of the matrix of the linear map , (), are 0 except that the entries in row , column , equal 1 for 1≤≤dim()

I have seen that there are a couple of answers on this site (for example [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2951574/prove-that-all-entries-in-mt-v-1-v-n-w-1-w-m-are-zero-exc)), but I am still struggling to get a clear and understandable solution that is also in the notation and follows the order of Axler's text. I understand that a matrix is always with respect to bases from the vector spaces involved...is the question asking me to give examples of the two bases? I'm just very perplexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's prepare our setting:

1- Let $dimV=n$ and $dimW=m$.

2- Let $dim rangeT= k$ and $dim nullT = s$. Note that, by "Rank-Nullity Theorem"(3.22 in Axler's Book), $k+s=n$.

Step1 : Let $B_{1}=(a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{s})$ be a basis of nullT.

Step2: Extend $B_{1}$ to a basis of $V$, say, $B=(v_{1},v_{2},..v_{k},a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{s})$.

Step3: Using the idea in proof of (3.22), we know that $B_{2}=(Tv_{1},Tv_{2},...,Tv_{k})$ is a basis of rangeT.

Step4: Similar to step2, we can extend $B_{2}$ to a basis of $W$, which is $B^{'}=(Tv_{1},Tv_{2},...,Tv_{k},w_{k+1},...,w_{m})$.

Step5: Now, you need to observe that $M(T,B,B^{'})$ is in the desired form.

Comment: Thank you, that is a solid explanation. I think what would be good to point out maybe for future readers is that T(a_1), ..., T(a_s) will equal 0 because a_1,...,a_s is the basis of the null of T.